# notebook lines in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

I thought it might be cute to introduce notebook lines in my text.  Also it may help readers from straining their eyes.  Let's use the classic filler text:

> Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
>
> Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.
>
> But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us -- that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.

Blah blah blah.  I could like this paragraph to appear as a notebook with  a faint line, perhaps - `black!20!white` underneath each line.

Is this styling possible?  Here is a cute html example on [Bezier curves](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/)

[image]

---

Is it possible to add these lines without resorting to adding another package like `background` ?

Comment: that blog has some beautiful diminishing effects that I can do without.  That left margin could be very useful as well... If I recall the horizontal line is `\hrule` and the § symbol is `\S`

Comment: You might be able to combine this method for creating lines: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141527/how-to-create-a-lined-page-with-line-numbers with text. If you could get that working, it would probably be preferable, as it's more flexible than a background image: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex Someone else may have a more advanced way to utilize the method for adding lines to the page, as this is a bit out of my area of expertise. This should give you a starting point, though.

Comment: @AlanMunn is it really necessary to use the **background** package ?

Comment: @Alan_Munn - This question pertains to creating a text document with lines in the background, whereas the other post is about creating lines on an otherwise blank document. They're definitely related, but because of that difference, I don't believe it's a duplicate.

Comment: @john_mangual - This web page shows the work of someone who was trying to do something similar to what you seem to want: http://www.highschoolmathandchess.com/2013/05/25/latex-handwriting-on-notebook-paper/ -- Their .tex file and notebook paper background image is here: http://www.highschoolmathandchess.com/resources/handouts/ (Scroll down.)